# Sum up integer values of an int[]-parameter and return the result

Tags: java, arrays, integer

How can I sum up the integer values of an int[]-parameter and return the result

```
Sample1: [1,2,3] must return 6
Sample2: [-7,7,3] must return 3
Sample3: [] must return 0
```

```
public static int calculateSum(int[] values) {
        int[] array = {10, 20, 30, 40};
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you were given a sequence of numbers: how would you sum up these by hand? How could such an algorithm be implemented by a computer?

Comment: Do you know about loops and how to access array elements? If not, I'd suggest you grab a tutorial and learn about that. If you know it, what prevents you from calculating the sum?

Comment: There is dozens of solutions on the internet, google that and you would have the solution in a second

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This, as most questions which give a strong impression of being a blind homework dump, lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying yourself. To improve have a look at the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and at [ask].

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try this

```
    public static int calculateSum(int[] values) {
        int result = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
            result += values[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because the OP should first try it - he doesn't learn anything without trying first (except that there is someone out there that is willing to do thier work for free).

Comment: Well, given the fact that the OP didn't state anything else the reason might be as ell laziness - and we should not support that. We generally expect people to first put some effort into finding a solution (and even using google on this is not too hard) as is also outlined in [ask].

Comment: Why should I, the OP, or anyone else for that matter "try this"? Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.